# jQuery sort order by data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I have some items in a div that are have the data attribute of `data-order` attached to them:

```
<div class="list">
   <a href="#" data-order="4">Thing 4</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="3">Thing 3</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="1">Thing 1</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="2">Thing 2</a>
</div>
```

But I'm trying to get them so they display the numerical order (ascending - 1,2,3, etc.):

```
<div class="list">
   <a href="#" data-order="1">Thing 1</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="2">Thing 2</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="3">Thing 3</a>
   <a href="#" data-order="4">Thing 4</a>
</div>
```

I have this:

```
  $(".list a").sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).attr("data-order") > $(b).attr("data-order");
  }).each(function() {
    $(".list").prepend(this);
  });
```

But that seems to **really** mess the order up. So I'm not too sure what I'm doing incorrectly or if there might be a simpler way to go about getting them to sort correctly.

Comment: What do you expect `new Date` to accomplish?

Comment: Whoops! That might be a typo....
I was looking at another example that as using date to sort.

Comment: @GeorgeJempty - I updated it and removed the `new Date`

Comment: It's working for me now: https://repl.it/@dexygen/sortHrefs

Comment: @GeorgeJempty Your html is already in order. If you mix them up, it does not work.

Comment: for data attributes you can access them like this `$(a).data("order")`

Comment: Oops I must have grabbed the wrong html snippet

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A few things:

1. `sort` should not return a boolean, but rather a negative, positive, or zero<sup>*</sup>:

   ```
   if (a  <  b) return -1; //negative
   if (a  >  b) return 1;  //positive
   if (a === b) return 0;  //0
   ```

   Easier expressed as:

   ```
   return a - b;
   ```
2. You can use `appendTo()` in place of `.each( .append() )`, which I'd expect to perform slightly better.
3. `.attr("data-order")` can be expressed as `.data("order")` (though this is more a matter of preference).

```js
$(".list a")
    .sort((a,b) => $(a).data("order") - $(b).data("order"))
    .appendTo(".list");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <a href="#" data-order="4">Thing 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="3">Thing 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="1">Thing 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="2">Thing 2</a>
</div>
```

---

Taking it one step further, you could even create your own jQuery plugin/method:

```
$(".list").sortChildren();
```

```js
$.fn.sortChildren = function() {
    this
      .children()
      .sort((a,b) => $(a).data("order") - $(b).data("order") || -1)
      .appendTo(this);

    return this;
}

$(".list").sortChildren();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <a href="#" data-order="4">Thing 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="3">Thing 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="1">Thing 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="2">Thing 2</a>
</div>
```

---

*Thanks to [charlieftl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) for the slight correction.

With his note that the `sort()` doesn't have to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, we gain a few things:

- We can simply do `a - b` to determine sort order
- We no longer need to parse the values. The `-` operator can only be used with numeric values, therefore it will parse `a` and `b` on its own.

Comment: *" It should return one of three values"* is not absolute. Rule is really ... positive number, negative number or zero

Comment: Cool, this makes sense of things. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your sort comparison operator to **`-`** from **`>`** which will cast the values to numbers and the subtraction will return numeric value that is positive, negative or zero

Can also use `html(function)` or `append(function)`

```js
$(".list").append(function() {
  return $(this).children().sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).attr("data-order") - $(b).attr("data-order");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
  <a href="#" data-order="4">Thing 4</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="3">Thing 3</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="1">Thing 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-order="2">Thing 2</a>
</div>
```